# Vue table row live search and filter without inserting in data methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm going to directly create a table element in the vue template, **not parsing table row data in the script data methods**. My question is how can I achieve a table live search function? Only the matched rows will show when values entered in the live search input. My rough idea is to add `v-if` directives to every `tr` or `td` element, and whenever the values entered, only the `tr` element with matched content will show and others will hide. But this would be somewhat a waste of time. Do you have any better ideas? Thank you in advance.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ernst Handel</td>
          <td>Roland Mendel</td>
          <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Island Trading</td>
          <td>Helen Bennett</td>
          <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
          <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
          <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
          <td>Italy</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: you can try like https://github.com/Jebasuthan/vue_crud_bootstrap

Comment: This is just a bad idea...¨

Comment: The reason why I want to find an alternative solution is because I have many tables to insert in different pages. It would be very time-consuming if I type all values one by one in the data method.